# How can I update all the packages inside the package.json and package-lock.json files?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a website and I haven't updated it for about a year. I need to update all the packages in "package.json" and "package-lock.json" and I have no clue how to do it. I would be grateful for any suggestion. The Node version I'm using is 16.15.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You can update packages in `package.json` with these steps:

1- Navigate to the root directory of your project and ensure it contains a `package.json` file:

```
cd /path/to/project
```

2- In your project root directory, run the update command:

```
npm update
```

3-To test the update, run the outdated command. There should not be any output.

```
npm outdated
```

And for `package-lock.json` follow these steps:

1- Delete your `package-lock.json` file in the root directory of your project,

2- Simply run `npm install` as in default, it checks if your directory has `package-lock.json` file otherwise, it will create one for you. (This command will honour the ^ and ~ symbol and update the packages to its latest that is provided by the library author(s)).

**Information about ^ and ~ :**

In `package.json`, a version can have a `^` in front (e.g. ^0.12.31), meaning the latest minor release may be safely installed.

Tilde `(~)` in front (e.g., ~0.12.31) means the latest patch release is safe to install.

Comment: I remember there was an npm application that was better than `npm update` but I don't recall its name. I can't remove the package-lock.json because it is already in git and hosted on a static website server through github.

Comment: You can commit it and push it after update  so that other dev members can leverage it.

Comment: Nothing gets updated in package.json after running `npm update`

Comment: I will try npm-check-updates